# Fix CoreNLP sentence splitting with European dates

Tags: nlp, date-parsing, stanford-nlp

Stanford CoreNLP does not work with many common European date formats (c.f. [Date and time notation in Europe (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Europe)).

We all know that date parsing is a mess, in particular the [crazy mm-dd-yyyy format the U.S. uses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSr0j.jpg). Nevertheless, CoreNLP is unable to process even basic European date formats, because it splits too aggressively on dots.

However, date information is often presented e.g. as:

> Die Terroranschläge am 11. September 2001, einem Dienstag, waren vier koordinierte Flugzeugentführungen mit anschließenden Selbstmordattentaten ... [(Wikipedia)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terroranschl%C3%A4ge_am_11._September_2001)

Whatever I try, CoreNLP splits this into:

```
1. Die Terroranschläge am 11.
2. September 2001, einem Dienstag, waren vier [...]
```

making CoreNLP largely unusable for German NLP. The dot simply marks this as ordinal numbers, i.e. this is the German way of writing "11th September 2001". You will also see the Notation "11. 9. 2001" in German frequently, CoreNLP thinks `9.` is another sentence, and also "11. Sept. 2001"

Is there any hook (e.g. overriding some method) that would allow me to define patterns to re-join incorrectly split sentences with own rules? For example, `[123]?\d\. 1?\d\.` would be typical for dates, and there are not many months...

Comment: Hi I'll work on getting it restarted!

Comment: You could simply remove the dots from the input string with such a pattern. But that is a hack.

Comment: I am experimenting with such a thing - replacing them with spaces for now, to keep character offsets intact. But it would be better if this were supported by CoreNLP out of the box.

Comment: I will work on fixing this at some point but it will require some changes to the sentence splitter which is rule based.

Answer (score 0):

While this isn't a solution involving CoreNLP, in a bit of a shameless self-plug let me advertise my own (Python-based) sentence splitter and word tokenizer, [segtok](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/segtok); [GitHub](https://github.com/fnl/segtok). After reading this complaint, I realized that my own segmenter also did not support this functionality, so I've added it just now and pushed the update to PyPI and GitHub.

I like to think that, generally, it delivers quite nice results, and it has some "expert knowledge" for European-specific issues (I speak Spanish, English, and German fluently and grasp a bit about other European languages) so you might want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted a workaround in the bug report:

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/issues/380

Essentially, I wrap the existing `TokenizerAnnotator` with one that merges dots into the previous token, if there is no character inbetween and the previous token is all numeric. This should be reasonably efficient - much more efficient than regexp based approaches.

Comment: While this *can* be faster than a regex (which can also be implemented as a linear, scanning implementation [as a DFA, e.g., RE2] and therefore be no slower than this solution), you will now be merging all sentences that end with digits. Maybe that (digits before sentence terminals) is less frequent in your particular corpus, but overall, its unlikely to be a good solution.

Comment: Yes, there could be false positives the other way now. But I do see a lot of these, and usually errors with bad splits are more severe for me. I had *many* errors with CoreNLPs defaults, up to the point where I was really unhappy with its performance, and was considering to explore alternatives. For now, this is "good enough" again (with some more hacks like this). The sentence splitter of CoreNLP definitely needs more work and direct evaluation.